# Having problems with decrementing particular variables for particular touch events active at once, on the screen

Tags: android, libgdx

So I am making a game where the user places four fingers of their hand on the screen which produces four circles on those touches on the screen and indicators above these with an offset. An indicator goes off on a particular circle and the user requires to touch up which increments their score and back down to the circle they lifted their finger from. I have four variables which handle the scoring for each of these fingers for reasons to use them as statistics later on, the incrementing part of the game works as it should. However, my problem is when decrementing, at times the scores for each circle decrements properly but most times it is not doing it correctly.

Below is the segment of code where my problem is currently:

```
public void scoreDeducter(OrthographicCamera cam, float elapsedTime,
        int currentIndex) {

    //the for loop iterating over the 4 circles on the screen
    for (int placerIndex = 0; placerIndex < placerCoordinates.length; placerIndex++) {
        Vector3 placerVector = new Vector3(
                placerCoordinates[placerIndex].x,
                placerCoordinates[placerIndex].y, 0);

        cam.unproject(placerVector);
        //the currentIndex is where the indicator has gone green and so to avoid
        //the score to decrement for that pointer we don't execute the inner loop
        //as we would like to increment score on touch up.
        if (currentIndex != placerIndex) {
            //goes through the various touch coordinates currently on the screen
            for (int pointer = 0; pointer < 5; pointer++) {

                Vector3 touchVector = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(pointer),
                        Gdx.input.getY(pointer), 0);
                //we unproject the pointer's coordinates x and y
                cam.unproject(touchVector);

                //this is the distance between the placer (circle) and the touch on the screen
                //for the pointer
                float distance = placerVector.dst(touchVector.x,
                        touchVector.y, 0);
                int radius = 20;

                //checks whether this pointer has been touched
                boolean isCurrentTouched = Gdx.input.isTouched(pointer);
                //boolean isCurrentTouched = Gdx.input.isTouched();

                //if the distance is less than the circle's radius and is touched
                //then we know that the person hasn't made an error, therefore we skip the
                //pointer to 5, without making any further checks whether it is touched or not.
                if (distance < radius && isCurrentTouched) {

                    pointer = 5;
                }

                //otherwise should the pointer's value be 4 and the if statement
                //condition above fails we decrement the score off a circle as they
                //lifted their finger on the placer where the indicator hasn't gone green
                else if (pointer == 4) {
                    if (elapsedTime >= 5.0f && !isCurrentTouched) {

                        if (placerIndex == 0 && f1Score != 0) {
                            f1Score = f1Score - 1;
                        }
                        if (placerIndex == 1&& f2Score != 0) {

                            f2Score = f2Score - 1;
                        }
                        if (placerIndex == 2 && f3Score != 0) {
                            f3Score = f3Score - 1;
                        }
                        if (placerIndex == 3 && f4Score != 0) {
                            f4Score = f4Score - 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This then gets rendered in my GameRenderer class in render method:

```
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    System.out.println("f1 score: " + world.getFingerPlacer().getF1Score()
            + " f2 score: " + world.getFingerPlacer().getF2Score()
            + " f3 score: " + world.getFingerPlacer().getF3Score()
            + " f4 score: " + world.getFingerPlacer().getF4Score());

    // System.out.println("f1 Errors: " + f1Errors + " f2 Errors: " +
    // f2Errors + " f3Errors: " + f3Errors + " f4Errors: " + f4Errors);

    // System.out.println("The score: "+
    // world.getFingerPlacer().getTotalScore());

    if ((!world.getFingerPlacer().arePlacersFilled() && !world
            .getIndicator().areIndicatorsFilled()) && Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        world.getFingerPlacer().addFingerPlacers();
        world.getIndicator().generateCoords();
    }

    if (world.getFingerPlacer().arePlacersFilled()
            && world.getIndicator().areIndicatorsFilled()) {

        // we sort the lists so that the indicators match with the
        // corresponding placers
        world.bubblesort(world.getFingerPlacer().getPlacerCoords());
        world.bubblesort(world.getIndicator().getIndicatorCoords());

        // the rendering of the placers take place
        renderFingerPlacers();
        renderIndicators();
        renderIndicatorColour(delta);
        timeKeeper(delta);

    }
}
```

And my scoreDeducter() method gets called in the renderIndicatorColour method:

```
public void renderIndicatorColour(float delta) {

    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);

    shapeRenderer.setColor(50 / 130f, 210 / 130f, 56 / 130f, 1f);

    Vector3 touchVector = new Vector3(world.getIndicator()
            .getIndicatorCoords()[index].x, world.getIndicator()
            .getIndicatorCoords()[index].y, 0);

    camera.unproject(touchVector);

    shapeRenderer.rect(touchVector.x, touchVector.y, 20, 10);
    shapeRenderer.end();

    elapsedTime += delta;

    justTouchedUp = Gdx.input.getInputProcessor().touchUp(
            (int) world.getFingerPlacer().getPlacerCoords()[index].x,
            (int) world.getFingerPlacer().getPlacerCoords()[index].y, 0, 0);

    if (justTouchedUp) {

        wasTouchedUp = true;
    }

    world.getFingerPlacer().scoreDeducter(camera, elapsedTime, index);

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't have time to dig through your code but you ought to be informed-  high levels of multitouch can be a fragile thing.  Depending on the capicitance and size of indidvidual fingers and the quality of the hardware, you can see false touch downs and touch ups in the data, especially if the fingers are close together.  You can also sometimes see 2 fingers merge and look like 1, with or without a position change.  This may be part of your issue.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks you for the response,I tested this and this doesn't seem to be an issue, as the incrementation of scores work perfectly which would have not been working properly had this been the case, plus I am dealing with 5 pointers at most, mobile devices now can take up to a maximum of 20 pointers. Additionally, I have tested this to see on a less-powerful mobile device (Sony Xperia P) as opposed to the Sony Xperia Z1 Compact which is my newer phone, I have had no problems.

Comment: @GabeSechan All I know is the issue is with checking for the pointer in which a circle is touched by, and if none are, then to decrement the score for that.